# Constructor parameter "this" working from activity but from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I used a constructor like this:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] ids;
    private String[] names;
    private String[] urls;
    private String[] fileTypes;
    private String[] date_times;
    private Activity context;    
public CustomList(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] names, String[] str_url,String[] fileType ,String[] dateTime){
            super(context, R.layout.list_view_layout, ids);
            this.context = context;
            this.ids = ids;
            this.names = names;
            this.urls = str_url;
            this.fileTypes = fileType;
            this.date_times = dateTime;
        }
```

And able to use this class from main activity like this

```
CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.names,ParseJSON.url,ParseJSON.file_type,ParseJSON.uploaded_at);
```

But whenever I am trying to pass the first parameter of constructor "this" error message showing. So what will be the first parameter whenever using that calass from a fragment

---

This is actually what I have done in a fragment

```
if (arrayListPollingSite.size() > 0) {
                int pollingSiteCount = arrayListPollingSite.size();
                pollingSiteNameArray = new String[pollingSiteCount];
                HashMap<String, String> pollDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < pollingSiteCount; i++) {
                    pollDataMap = arrayListPollingSite.get(i);
                    pollingSiteNameArray[i] = pollDataMap.get(i);
                   // this line showing error  
                    CustomList c1=new CustomList(getActivity(),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID));
                }
               // listView.setAdapter(cl);

            }
```

Comment: you should use `context.getActivity()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 1):

'this' means always the current context.
the fragment's context and the activity's context are different.

so you should give the activity's context to the constructor: try 'getActivity()'

Comment: I have tried this.  showing error "Expected actual arguments".

Comment: Try replacing 'Activity' in the first parameter of the constructor by 'Context'.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `this` from the Activity class.
But in a fragment you must call the activity that contain this fragment with `getActivity()`, like this:

```
CustomList cl = new CustomList(getActivity(), ParseJSON.ids,
                ParseJSON.names,ParseJSON.url,ParseJSON.file_type,
                ParseJSON.uploaded_at);
```

---

Harunduet said:
I have tried according to the following way;

```
pollingSiteNameArray = new String[pollingSiteCount];
CustomList c1=new CustomList(getActivity(),pollingSiteNameArray[1],pollingSiteNameArray[2],pollingSiteNameArray[3],pollingSiteNameArray[4],pollingSiteNameArray[5]);
```

it show error

---

Harunduet said:

```
 if (arrayListPollingSite.size() > 0) {
                int pollingSiteCount = arrayListPollingSite.size();
                pollingSiteNameArray = new String[pollingSiteCount];
                HashMap<String, String> pollDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < pollingSiteCount; i++) {
                    pollDataMap = arrayListPollingSite.get(i);
                    pollingSiteNameArray[i] = pollDataMap.get(i);
                   // this line showing error  
                    CustomList c1=new CustomList(getActivity(),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID),pollDataMap.get(Constants.KEY_COUNTY_ID));
                }
               // listView.setAdapter(cl);

            }
```

---

Where are you exe this code? Try to move to `onActivityCreated` method, in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
CustomList cl = new CustomList(getActivity(), ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.names,ParseJSON.url,ParseJSON.file_type,ParseJSON.uploaded_at);
```